# how to print the text of error in angular?

Tags: angular

error in console

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at 
XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:8901:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
text: "Assigned"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8009/admin/4/103"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
```

how to display error in console

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

If you want to display it in the html you can do it like so:

```
  <p *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</p>
```

If you want to display the error as a notification let's say, use a toaster library or create your own notification service and pass the error message as an argument.